# checking inline value is exists, set to object property in declaring object _ JavaScript

Tags: javascript

suppose we want to create a new object.

```
let myObject = {};
```

and we have some property that exists in another object like :

```
let b = { foo: "bar"};
```

is it possible to check if b?.foo append foo to myObject inline in the declaration of the object?

something like this :

```
let myObject = { b?.foo }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best you can do is :

```js
let myObject = {
  some: "prop",
  ...(b?.foo && {foo:b.foo})
}
```

Or if you want to pass all the object

```js
let myObject = {
  some: "prop",
  ...(b?.foo && b)
}
```